# c++ qt range of excel querySubObject

Tags: c++, qt, range, export-to-excel

I try to write Data from Qt into an excel-File. I found this piece of code letting me write my Data into an 5*5 range.

```
//get a 5x5 range of cells : from A1 to E5
QAxObject *range = sheet1->querySubObject( "Range(const QString&, const QString&)", QString("A1"), QString("f5")); 
QVariant vTable(table);
range->dynamicCall("SetValue(const QVariant&)", vTable);
```

My data is much bigger than 5 colums and 5 rows and varies in size. Is there a possibility of setting the range with numbers something like:

```
QAxObject *range = sheet1->querySubObject( "Range(7,123)");
```

meaning my data should have the size of 7 columns and 123 rows ?

Thanks very much for your answers

Itelly

Answer (score 0):

If your data is 123x7 table then you can initialize your range as

```
QAxObject *range = sheet1->querySubObject( "Range(A1,G123)");
```

Assuming that you are storing your values in vTable then you can call :

```
range->dynamicCall("setValue(const QVariant&)",vTable);
```

to put your values to spreadsheet.