# How to delete table rows in word using Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I want to delete some table rows in a doc file by using QAxobject,like this:

```
QAxObject* range_delete = table->querySubObject("Rows(int)", 6);
if (range_delete) {
    range_delete->dynamicCall("Delete()");
}
```

but it doesn't work,the range_delete always get Null.
So, How can i do this in a correct way ?
And then what if the number of rows is greater than 1?

Comment: I don't know the exact problem, but why do you query `Columns(int)` when you want to delete rows?

Comment: For getting a range you can try using excel syntax like in: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28671649/c-qt-range-of-excel-querysubobject

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a way to solve this problem.
I found that, when there are vertically merged cells in the table, individual rows cannot be selected,So, the range_delete always get null.And then, I choose the oher way to select the row that I want to delete.
the code:

```
//step one ,select the cell that the row contains
QAxObject* cells = table_object->querySubObject("Cell(int,int)", i, 1);
//step two, get the row
QAxObject* range = cells->querySubObject("Range");
QAxObject* row = range_a->querySubObject("Rows"); 
//step three, delete it
row->dynamiCall("Delete()");
```

Finally, it worked.
PS:All of this is about the tables in the Doc file.